# Why does display:none on ::after and ::before alter spacing within parent element?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I was trying to dissect the example provided in the Portfolio project over at FreeCodeCamp. Note that Boostrap is being employed in this design. Here's the relevant segment of HTML:

```
<header id="banner" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#top" class="scrollable">LINK</a>
    <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" class="navbar-toggle collapsed">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <nav id="navbar" role="navigation" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#top" class="scrollable">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio" class="scrollable">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" class="scrollable">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

And the relevant CSS:

```
#banner .container{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:95%;
  max-width:1024px;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
}

#banner{
  background-color:#722872 !important;
  height:80px;
  box-shadow:0px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-color:#592059;
}

#banner .container::before, #banner .container::after{
  display:none
}

nav{
  font-size:13px;
  background:#722872;
  -webkit-transition:all .3s;
  transition:all .3s;
}

.nav>li{
  height:100%;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:bold;
  letter-spacing:2px;
  display:inline-flex;
}

.nav>li a{
  color:#ffffff;
  padding:10px 20px;
}

.navbar-toggle{
  margin-right:0;
}

#top{
  height:80px;
  display:block;
}
```

I was surprised to see that line setting the display of the container class element's ::after and ::before pseudos to 'none,' and even more surprised to see that removing this setting results in the elements of the nav being squeezed closer together. I looked over the descriptions on MDN and nothing jumped out to me as explaining how this works. You can view the code in action [here](http://codepen.io/elemkeh/pen/mOXPGJ). I was under the impression pseudo elements had no effect on layout unless they were explicitly made to.

Comment: Because each element (including pseudo elements) are considered as children of flex?

Comment: As expected: `In-flow ::after and ::before pseudo-elements are now flex items (bug 867454).`